# How to solve this Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException): The bucket doesn't exist

Tags: magento2, category, layered-navigation, exception

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException): The bucket doesn't exist.

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException): The bucket doesn't exist.

```
#1 Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor->getFacetedData('category') called at [vendor\magento\module-catalog-search\Model\Layer\Filter\Category.php:113]
#2 Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Category->_getItemsData() called at [vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter.php:202]
#3 Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter->_initItems() called at [vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter.php:159]
#4 Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter->getItems() called at [vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter.php:148]
#5 Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter->getItemsCount() called at [vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Layer\Category\AvailabilityFlag.php:33]
#6 Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\AvailabilityFlag->canShowOptions(array(&Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Category#000000001a335681000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a3354b7000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a33545f000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a33545e000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a3354f2000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a3354ad000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Price#000000001a335441000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a33545d000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a33545c000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a3354f3000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a335440000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a3354cf000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a335451000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a3354c8000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a3354cc000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a3354cb000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a3354c6000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a3354cd000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a335210000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a335211000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a3355a2000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a3355bd000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a335448000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a3355be000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a335446000000004a488cc7#)) called at [vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Layer\Category\AvailabilityFlag.php:23]
#7 Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\AvailabilityFlag->isEnabled(&Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category#000000001a33544e000000004a488cc7#, array(&Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Category#000000001a335681000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a3354b7000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a33545f000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a33545e000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a3354f2000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a3354ad000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Price#000000001a335441000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a33545d000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a33545c000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a3354f3000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a335440000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a3354cf000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a335451000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a3354c8000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a3354cc000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a3354cb000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a3354c6000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a3354cd000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a335210000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a335211000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a3355a2000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a3355bd000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a335448000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a3355be000000004a488cc7#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000001a335446000000004a488cc7#)) called at [vendor\magento\module-layered-navigation\Block\Navigation.php:126]
#8 Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation->canShowBlock() called at [vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\Magento_LayeredNavigation\templates\layer\view.phtml:15]
#9 include('C:\xampp73\htdoc...') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php.php:59]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation#000000001a3355a3000000004a488cc7#, 'C:/xampp73/htdoc...', array('csp' => &Magento\Csp\Helper\InlineUtil#000000001a33534f000000004a488cc7#)) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:58]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callParent('render', array(&Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation#000000001a3355a3000000004a488cc7#, 'C:/xampp73/htdoc...', array('csp' => &Magento\Csp\Helper\InlineUtil#000000001a33534f000000004a488cc7#))) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:138]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation#000000001a3355a3000000004a488cc7#, 'C:/xampp73/htdoc...', array()) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:153]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callPlugins('render', array(&Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation#000000001a3355a3000000004a488cc7#, 'C:/xampp73/htdoc...', array()), array(array('csp_helper_plugi...'))) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor.php:26]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->render(&Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation#000000001a3355a3000000004a488cc7#, 'C:/xampp73/htdoc...', array()) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php:271]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('C:/xampp73/htdoc...') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php:301]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:1100]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:1104]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:674]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:566]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('catalog.leftnav') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:542]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('catalog.leftnav') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:206]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('catalog.leftnav') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:497]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('catalog.leftnav', false) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:193]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('catalog.leftnav', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:594]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('sidebar.main', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:544]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('sidebar.main') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:206]
#27 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('sidebar.main') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:497]
#28 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('sidebar.main', false) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:193]
#29 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('sidebar.main', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:594]
#30 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('div.sidebar.main', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:544]
#31 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('div.sidebar.main') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:206]
#32 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('div.sidebar.main') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:497]
#33 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('div.sidebar.main', false) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:193]
#34 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('div.sidebar.main', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:594]
#35 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:544]
#36 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:206]
#37 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('columns') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:497]
#38 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns', false) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:193]
#39 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('columns', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:594]
#40 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:544]
#41 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:206]
#42 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.content') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:497]
#43 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content', false) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:193]
#44 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.content', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:594]
#45 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:544]
#46 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:206]
#47 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:497]
#48 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:193]
#49 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:594]
#50 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:544]
#51 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:206]
#52 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:497]
#53 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:193]
#54 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:963]
#55 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:58]
#56 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('getOutput', array()) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:138]
#57 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:153]
#58 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', array(), array(array('layout-model-cac...'))) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:494]
#59 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Page.php:258]
#60 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000001a33587c000000004a488cc7#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Layout.php:171]
#61 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000001a33587c000000004a488cc7#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:58]
#62 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000001a33587c000000004a488cc7#)) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:138]
#63 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000001a33587c000000004a488cc7#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:153]
#64 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000001a33587c000000004a488cc7#), array(array('result-messages', 'result-builtin-c...', 'result-varnish-c...'))) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor.php:130]
#65 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000001a33587c000000004a488cc7#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php:120]
#66 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor.php:24]
#67 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php:261]
#68 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#000000001a335863000000004a488cc7#) called at [index.php:39]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can resolve exception on category page “Bucket does not exist” by one of the below solution:

1. One of reason because of Page Cache, Static resource or Indexer not updated. So try remove /var/ and /pub/static/ (do not remove .htaccess) Run following command.

   php bin/magento cache:flush

   php bin/magento setup:upgrade

   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

   php bin/magento indexer:reindex

   php bin/magento setup:di:compile (optional)
2. Problem with layered navigation, when we try to change or select sub category when base/parent category is set as anchor. Probably solution we can set value of  “No” of base/parent category and once again change it to “No”. It should resolve our problem and sub category page will work from layer navigation.

Comment: Hi @HirenPatel thanks for your great help. I tried these solutions second solution is somehow work for me but if (RootCategory->ParentCategory->ChildCategory) i can set anchor value of RootCategory as "YES" and ParentCategory as "YES" than it's work properly, but if i set value of anchor ParentCategory as "YES" it's not working and i got exception like above. It's not proper solution for me so please help me how to resolve it's by another way.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with indexing for catalog search full text data

Comment: Heyy @HirenPatel thanks for your answer but, it's not working for me. Is there any another  way to solve this issue?